# Avoid the use of nested loop in multiple column comparison

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Patient.ID = rep(paste("Pat", seq(1:3), sep = ""), 2),
             Gene = c(rep("Gene1", 3), rep("Gene2", 3)),
             Ref = c("A", "C", "G", "T", "A", "T"),
             Tum1 = c("A", "A", "T", "T", "A", "T"),
             Tum2 = c("A", "C", "G", "G", "C", "C"))
```

What I would like to do is determine the change that is occurring between the Ref or either Tum column. In other words, if Tum1 is different from Tum2 take the character string which is different to the Ref column and store that in a separate column as the change so the dataframe above would become:

```
df <- data.frame(Patient.ID = rep(paste("Pat", seq(1:3), sep = ""), 2),
             Gene = c(rep("Gene1", 3), rep("Gene2", 3)),
             Ref = c("A", "C", "G", "T", "A", "T"),
             Tum1 = c("A", "A", "T", "T", "A", "T"),
             Tum2 = c("A", "C", "G", "G", "C", "C"),
             BaseChange = c("NoCh", "C.A", "G.T", "T.G", "A.C", "T.C"))
```

I'm aware I could use a nested ifelse() statement like below (but extended) to solve this, but my actual dataframe has many more combinations and I figure there has to be a "safer" method of doing so.

```
df$BaseChange <- as.factor(ifelse(df$Ref == "C" & df$Tum1 == "A" | df$Ref== "C" & df$Tum2 == "A", "C.A",
                              ifelse((df$Ref == "G" & df$Tum1 == "T" | df$Ref == "G" & df$Tum2 == "T"), "G.T",...)))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but would this suffice? `apply(df[3:5], 1, function(i) paste0(unique(i), collapse = '.'))`? Of course we can easily convert the first `A` to `NoChange`.

Comment: Wow. It was that simple, huh?
Works great. Submit as an answer and I'll mark as closed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but it works:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(BaseChange2 = ifelse( (as.character(Ref)==as.character(Tum1) & as.character(Ref) == as.character(Tum2)), "NoCh",
                                         ifelse(as.character(Ref)==as.character(Tum1),paste(Ref,Tum2, sep="."),paste(Ref,Tum1, sep="."))))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems tha you need to paste unique `Tum`s together, i.e.

```
apply(df[3:5], 1, function(i) paste0(unique(i), collapse = '.'))
#[1] "A"   "C.A" "G.T" "T.G" "A.C" "T.C"
```

To replace the first `A`,

```
v2 <- apply(df[3:5], 1, function(i) paste0(unique(i), collapse = '.'))
replace(v2, nchar(v2) == 1, 'NoChange')
#[1] "NoChange" "C.A"      "G.T"      "T.G"      "A.C"      "T.C"
```